# De-Clicking due to clocking issues

Tags: digital, clock, clicks

Hello everyone,

I've been assigned a task this morning that possibly some of you have been there and done.

My coworker received a recording of trumpets, sax, trombones, etc., big band stuff, which was tracked at a studio which had a digital mixboard. They recorded at 96K via a 48K digital board.

I don't know how it happened, but the resultant tracks have all sorts of little digital clicks (exactly the clicks you hear when your word clock or clocking device is not synced).

It's for a time sensitive project and he told me there is no way to get them to re-record (this was the first thing I told him after he told me this bad news).

Anyway, have any of you received tracks like this that had this exact problem? And what did you find was most effective in handling it?

Right now I'm just going through each track and penciling each click out - which is fine, but it's going to take up my time a bit and if I can get it done faster, that would be best for everyone involved, including the client's wallet. This is after trying Izotope, X-Crackle, X-Click and the Sonnox restore plug-ins to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: ouch! sympathies man...i hate to say it, but the manual labor is probably the only method to really deal with that (besides your intelligent suggestion to re-record). goodl luck.

Comment: Thanks, Shaun. Well, guess it's back to the click mines for me... Seeya ;-)

Comment: @Shaun For the smaller back-up double instruments I copied the audio to another track and linear-phase EQed the whole track with a low-pass at 5K and copied up 2 or 3 cycles to cover up where the glitches were and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience batch processes really don't work well wrt to removing clicks.  RX spectral repair is amazing for that kind of stuff, but it still takes a manual select/render/playback process for each click, so still pretty time intensive.

I'd recommend that over penciling, but only marginally.

Comment: Thanks! Bah. I'll check back here in about an hour to thaw out my brain from the mind-numbing work ahead of me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I soooooo feel for you right now!

I've been on an NR / Click and Kill mission with a 12m long ADR scene that's non-stop dialog and It's been murder. There are hard drive clicks in the background and 3 Beep Bleed from the headphones through out the entire thing .

I feel like I've been listening to the same CD skipping for my entire life. I have found that iZotope Spectral Repair has been a lifesaver in this process (otherwise drawing waveforms out as well), though without it I'd tell them to get f'd or re-record (I've come close a few times but my professionalism and pride won't allow me. I'm finally about done with it as of this weekend and it will be a very long time or a retarded high paycheck before I take on another ADR/DX Editing gig.

Best of luck to you and let us know what works out!

Comment: Thanks, Syndicate. I just wrapped it up now. The mixer said I was his hero - he needs to get it mixed in the next 2 hours. 13 tracks of brass at 4 minutes long. It was difficult because most of it was long, held saxophone, trombone and trumpet notes with glitches in them so penciling was extremely difficult because it was almost the same as penciling a frickin' sine wave. I ended up also doing what I mentioned to Shaun above - EQing a separate track and coping just the few cycles of waveform I needed. Man, long day. Spent 12 hours on that. I'm looking forward to my soft pillow.